# How to hide the Models section in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui

I use [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) to display API documentation. By default, it displays the "Models" section at the bottom:

[image]

How to hide it?

Comment: Anyone can provide direct swagger UI hide fix?

Comment: Hope this answer help those who are working with Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633900/17839111

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To hide the "Models" section, add `defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1` to the Swagger UI configuration code in your `index.html`.

Note the option name uses plural `Model*s*` not `Model`.

```js
// index.html

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  // Begin Swagger UI call region
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,   // <-------
```

Swagger UI also has many other [configuration options](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md) that control API documentation rendering.

Comment: how can i do it using nelmio_api_doc.yml?

Comment: @samar please [ask a new question](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 21):

For .Net Core 3.0 just Add c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1); on your Startup.cs

```c#
// Startup.cs

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1); // Disable swagger schemas at bottom
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Your API V1");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In Docket bean just add 
new

`Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).ignoredParameterTypes(YourClass.class,YourAnother.class)`

I hope its helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder//
            .builder()//
            .defaultModelsExpandDepth(-1)//
            .build();//
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet answer. It helped me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If using Django add this inside your `settings.py`:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_DEPTH':-1
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Although not the exact results you are looking for but i find it perfect to just disable the properties of the model you don't want via:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

...

 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *         "normalization_context"={"groups"={"api"}},
 *         "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"api"}}
 *     },

...

 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Groups({"api","user:read"})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $disabledProperty;
```

This way you will get a model just with the props you exposed via the group `api`.
Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the first sentence of my answer! But the end result is the same as what the original question was looking for :)