# How to configure Swashbuckle to omit Template / Entity / Schema from the documentation

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to build a filter for Swashbuckle to omit in the API documentation the models / Entities / Schema of the project, keeping the controllers. The technology employed is Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v3.0.0 / Swagger UI v3.17.1. I already found ways to omit a certain method in the controller, but I wanted to omit the models in the documentation. I found a problem similar to mine, including hiding only the properties.

Follow filter code

```csharp
public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
{
    if (!(context.ApiModel is ApiObject))
    {
        return;
    }

    var model = context as ApiObject;

    if (schema?.Properties == null || model?.ApiProperties == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var excludedProperties = model.Type
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(
            t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null
        );

    var excludedSchemaProperties = model.ApiProperties
        .Where(
            ap => excludedProperties.Any(
                pi => pi.Name == ap.MemberInfo.Name
            )
        );

    foreach (var propertyToExclude in excludedSchemaProperties)
    {
         schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToExclude.ApiName);
    }
}
```

quote: [How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model#41006116)

Would anyone have any suggestions to hide only the models / Entities / Schemas from the documentation and not just their attributes? As the image below.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to hide the Models section in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57138564/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `DefaultModelsExpandDepth` to -1 in your Swashbuckle / Swagger UI configuration:

```csharp
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    ...
    c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion! But when using the line of code, it did not achieve the desired goal of omitting the schema / entity / model from the documentation.

Comment: Please make sure you used `DefaultModel*s*...` (with an "s") and not `DefaultModel...`

Comment: What's the difference between `DefaultModelExpandDepth`, `DefaultModelRendering`, `DefaultModelsExpandDepth`? They looks very similar in name, do they have similar functionality?

Comment: @liang please see Swagger UI docs for the description of each config option https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#display

Answer (score 1):

At least for me I had to do something like:

```
internal class SwaggerSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var keys = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        var prefix = "My.Prefix";
        foreach(var key in context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Keys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith(prefix))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }
        }

        foreach(var key in keys)
        {
            context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```