# How to hide ApiModel class in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

How to hide ApiModel class in Swagger?

I see hidden field in ApiModelProperty.

My client needs a models section, but doesn’t want to see one of the models in there.

Any pointers is appreciated, here!

Comment: you can hide full model section, similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57138564/8987128