# How to hide swagger models at bottom with gin-swagger?

Tags: api, go, swagger, document

I am using [gin-swagger](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger) for generating API document.

It shows `Models` at the bottom of the page list by default.

[image]

How to hide it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the Models section in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57138564/113116)

Answer (score 1):

You juste have to add this line

```
ginSwagger.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1))
```

like that

```
ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler,
        ginSwagger.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue before, I removed one annotation in comment and Models gone. But I could not remember the name of annotation, however, you can compare your annotaions with below and remove the additional one.

```golang
// @Summary Get all users
// @Description Get all users
// @Tags UserMgt
// @Accept  json
// @Produce  json
// @Param filter body object{UserFilter} true "filter"
// @Success 200  {array} object{models.User} "users"
// @Failure 400 {object} object{models.User} "users not found"
// @Router /user/all [post]
// @Security ApiKeyAuth
func GetAllUsers(ctx *gin.Context) {
  ....omitted....
}
```