# How to hide Models section from swagger UI in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have a spring boot project in which I have integrated the swagger, for API documentation.

Now the problem is by default it is displaying the **Models section**, which is a security concern. I have tried, but unable to hide it. Also have gone through this link here
[How to hide the Models section in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138564/how-to-hide-the-models-section-in-swagger-ui)

[image]

But in this also, they are refering to some index.html file, but I only have backend with no frontend. So how to achieve the same, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Look at this github link.

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-mvc/src/main/java/com/baeldung/swagger2boot/configuration/SpringFoxConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75955142/11532220) work for me!

```
@Bean
public UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()            
            .defaultModelsExpandDepth(-1)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)